# datum conversion from NAD27 + NGVD29 height (ftUS) to NAD27 + NAVD88 height (ftUS) using python

Tags: python, coordinate-transformation, pyproj, epsg

I am using python pyproj to convert  xyz values of Louisiana, USA region from NAD27 + NGVD29 height (ftUS) to NAD27 + NAVD88 height (ftUS). So, I am not changing the horizontal projection (because it's NAD27 for both), only the vertical projection is changing from NGVD29 to NAVD88.However, NAD83 + NAVD88 height (ftUS) should also work because NAD83 and NAD27 are almost same.

here is a sample code for a point (-89.8469444,31.23777778,2.73) where input height is 2.73 ft.

```
from pyproj import Transformer
from pyproj import CRS
#"epsg:7406" for NAD27 + NGVD29 height (ftUS)

t = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:7406", "epsg:8744", always_xy=True)#x is lon, y is lat
# t = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:5702", "epsg:6360", always_xy=True)# only z conversion
a=t.transform(-89.8469444,31.23777778,2.73)
print(a)
#CRS("epsg:8743") # Louisiana North
  
> output:

(3745443.9938408486, 998779.7596375213, 2.73)
```

So, the code gives me 2.73 ft as output but the right result should be 2.267 ft. Here is a [NOAA site](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/NCAT/) where I can verify the output should be 2.267 ft.
Here is another NOAA [Vdatum](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/vdatumweb/vdatumweb?a=091701920221025) site for the datum conversion which also gives me 2.267 ft. I highly appreciate any help.

Comment: There is a dedicated GIS stack exchange to answer these types of questions.  Take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340392/vertical-datum-transformation-using-pyproj

Answer (score 2):

There is a dedicated StackExchange for GIS questions.  Check it out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340392/vertical-datum-transformation-using-pyproj